# Arithmetical operations task with Objects

Tags: java, object

I've checked many stackOverflow questions about operations with objects but I haven't find the solution.

My task is to multiply and divide two objects with these constructors:

```
public class Fraction {
    private int denom;
    private int counter;

    public Fraction() {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.denom = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.denom = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int counter, int denom) {
            this.counter = counter;
        if (denom == 0) {
            this.denom = 1;
        } else
            this.denom = denom;
    }
}
```

What would be inside the "multiply" and "divide" methods?

```
public Fraction multiply(Fraction other) {

}

public Fraction divide(Fraction other) {

}
```

if this is what I need to use:

```
Fraction frac1 = new Fraction (2);
Fraction frac2 = new TortSzam(3,4);
fracResult = frac1.divide(frac2);
```

and the result is: 2.6666666666666665

What I tried by other StackOverflow Questions:

```
public Fraction multiply(Fraction other) {
        final Fraction multi = this;
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger;
        result.multiply(other);
}
```

But didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also put the code on what have you tried?

Comment: Do your fractions need to be stored in simplest form?  And do you know how to multiply and divide fractions?  (If not, this is probably more a mathematics question than a Java question).

Comment: It's going to be `return new Fraction(something, something else);`. `something` and `something else` are determined by primary school maths.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You might get some inspiration from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191436/calculate-with-fractions)

Comment: @YogeshBadke this is what I tried: 
' public Fraction multiply(Fraction other) {
            final Fraction multi = this;
            BigInteger result = new BigInteger;
            result.multiply(other);
        }'
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying two fractions just means multiplying the numerators, and then dividing that product by the multiplication of the denominators.  So you may try:

```
public Fraction multiply(Fraction other) {
    int counter = other.getCounter() * this.counter;
    int denim = other.getDenominator() * this.denom;

    return new Fraction(counter, denom);
}
```

I will leave the implementation of division up to you.  As a hint, the code would be very similar to the above except that you would use the inverse of one (but not both) of the two fraction inputs.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes the easiest task the hardest for me.